# Convert Factor to only Time in R

Tags: r

I have a got a dataframe having factor columns as shown below

```
df
ColA
14:59:33.0000000
15:59:33.0000000
16:59:33.0000000
17:59:33.0000000
```

ColA is a factor. Can we concert them to only time

Expected Output

```
df
ColA
14:59:33
15:59:33
16:59:33
17:59:33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strptime` and `format`.

```
format(strptime(v, "%T"), "%T")
# [1] "14:59:33" "15:59:33" "16:59:33" "17:59:33"
```

---

*Data*

```
v <- structure(1:4, .Label = c("14:59:33.0020000", "15:59:33.0000000", 
"16:59:33.0000000", "17:59:33.0000000"), class = "factor")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.ITime`

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(as.character(v))
#[1] "14:59:33" "15:59:33" "16:59:33" "17:59:33"
```

#### data

```
v <- structure(1:4, .Label = c("14:59:33.0020000", "15:59:33.0000000", 
 "16:59:33.0000000", "17:59:33.0000000"), class = "factor")
```